# Nopcommerce 3.3 Plugin for admin required

Tags: nopcommerce

I am looking to create nopCommerce plugin which will add menu in admin and from that menu i want to show a report view and than want to add report functionality on that view.

I am able to add menu in admin from plugin but when trying to access view from admin site its giving view not found error .

Thanks in advance if anyone can provide me any sample of admin plugin.

Regards
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.30 the views are embedded resource. Check the properties of the view and path in the method, which return this view.

This is working example:

```
return View("Nop.Plugin.Shipping.FixedRateShipping.Views.ShippingFixedRate.Configure");
```